# How to get the dateFormat from jQuery UI datepicker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

In my page, the datepicker dateFormat option is being set automatically by loading a localized .js file according to the current users's language settings. Elsewhere in the page, I need to format some dates, so I'd like to get the dateFormat option back out of the datePicker.

The [jQuery documentation says](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#method-option) you can retrieve the dateFormat option like so:

```
$('.selector').datepicker('option', 'dateFormat');
```

However, this returns a jQuery object wrapping the datePicker, not a string value as expected. Is this a bug? Is there another way to retrieve the dateValue option?

I'm using jQuery 1.3.2 and jQuery UI 1.7.1.

I know that I could simply look up the dateFormat another way, but pulling it out of the datepicker would be clean and elegant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using that method works for me<sup>1</sup>.  Are there multiple items with the selector class?  Do you know that the element has already been added as a date picker?

---

<sup>1</sup> On [the Date Picker demo site](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/), type `javascript:alert($("#datepicker").datepicker('option', 'dateFormat'));` into the address bar, and it will give you "mm/dd/yy."

Comment: Thanks. I noticed the datepicker demo siteis using jQuery-ui 1.7.2. I moved from 1.7.1 to 1.7.2 and everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a bug, and here's the bug report:
http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4301

UPDATE: the bug report indicates that this has already been fixed 3 years ago.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This isn't really the answer. The answer is "yes, it's a bug". I'll edit to make it clearer.